# Arduino Pin value gets stuck

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, serial, c, python

I'm using a Python program to send some message over serial port to Arduino. This message contains the pin number of the pin and whether it should be `HIGH` or `LOW` . Eg: Sending `2H\n` should set pin 2 to `HIGH`.

`pins` array maps the pin numbers in the messages to the actual pin number of arduino. `1H` corresponds to pin 22 on Arduinio Mega.

When manually sending one message at a time, things work fine. However when Python sends a series of 30 such messages one after the other in a loop with no delays, pin 1 is always stuck at whichever value it is set to on the first series of messages.

Example:

```
1L\n
2H\n
3H\n
4H\n
5H\n
...
```

followed by

```
1H\n
2H\n
3H\n
4H\n
5H\n
...
```

will cause pin 1 to be stuck at `LOW` when it should be high.

On arduino, this is the code that parse the message and sets the pin values.

```
void setPinValues(String message) {

  for(int i = 1; i <= sizeof(pins) / sizeof(pins[0]); i++ ) {
    String pinNumber = String(i);

    if( message == pinNumber + "H\n" ) {
      pinValues[i] = HIGH;
    }
    if( message == pinNumber + "L\n" ) {
      pinValues[i] = LOW;
    }
  }

}


void loop(){
    if( Serial.available() > 0 ) {
        received = Serial.read();
        message += received;
        if(received == '\n') {

            // Set pin values
            setPinValues(message);

            // Write to pins        
            for (int i = 1; i <= sizeof(pins) / sizeof(pins[0]); i++) {
                digitalWrite(pins[i], pinValues[i]);
            }

            // Clear buffer
            message = "";

        }       

    }

}
```

Arduino Mega communicates with Windows 8 x64 system over USB using a baud rate of 57600. When using a lower baud rate of 9600, this problem is not seen.

Furthermore, at baud rate of 57600, if I were to replace `setPinValues` with the following code, pin 1 is properly switched on and off.

```
void setPinValues(String message) {

  for(int i = 1; i <= sizeof(pins) / sizeof(pins[0]); i++ ) {
    if( message == String(1) + "H\n" ) {
      pinValues[1] = HIGH;
    }
    if( message == String(1) + "L\n" ) {
      pinValues[1] = LOW;
    }
    if( message == String(2) + "H\n" ) {
      pinValues[2] = HIGH;
    }
    if( message == String(2) + "L\n" ) {
      pinValues[2] = LOW;
    }
    if( message == String(3) + "H\n" ) {
      pinValues[3] = HIGH;
    }
    if( message == String(3) + "L\n" ) {
      pinValues[3] = LOW;
    }
  }

}
```

Doesnt both versions of `setPinValues` do the same? Why does lowering the baud rate prevent the problem? I cannot use a lower baud rate because the USB buffer gets filled up and things slow to a crawl.

---

To compare the last char `H` or `L`:

```
String pinValueString = message.substring(message.length() - 1);
char pinValueBuffer[2];
pinValueString.toCharArray(pinValueBuffer,2);

if(pinValueBuffer[0] == 'H') {
    digitalWrite(pins[pinNumber], HIGH);
}
```

Comment: Remember that you are on an embedded platform. You have to care about how efficient your code is. Here I would use an interrupt and buffer all received values. This way I would ensure that none of the received chr could be lost. And then, in a main loop I would process the content of the buffer and act on the pins accordingly. I could also light up a LED in case of the buffer gets full (to let you know). Or I could ensure that the processing is always faster than the rate at which the chr are received in the worst case.

Comment: @Blup1980 IIRC Arduino takes care of the serial interrupt for you. `Serial.available()` and `Serial.read()` are just wrappers around the serial buffer attached to the interrupt by Arduino when calling `Serial.begin()`, so he's actually already doing what you suggest :) The problem probably lies in the 128-byte buffer filling and dropping bytes due to the very slow processing.

Comment: Just FYI. There is now a stack dedicated to Arduino http://arduino.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if this is your problem, but `setPinValues` looks weird to me:

```
void setPinValues(String message) {
  for(int i = 1; i <= sizeof(pins) / sizeof(pins[0]); i++ ) {
    String pinNumber = String(i);

    if( message == pinNumber + "H\n" ) {
      pinValues[i] = HIGH;
    }
    if( message == pinNumber + "L\n" ) {
      pinValues[i] = LOW;
    }
  }
}
```

## Going out of bounds

Each time you call `setPinValues`, `i` will range from `1` to `length(pins)`, so if `pins` was declared as `pins[5]`, `i` will be `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` and `5`. Assuming `length(pins) == length(pinValues)` this is a problem in itself, because `pinValues[5]` would not even exist!

`pinValues[5]` only creates `pinValues[0]` to `pinValues[4]` (yes, I know it's weird, you're declaring 5 elements but, since C is 0-indexed, they're `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`), so `i` should **NEVER** reach 5 or you will be out of bounds which is undefined behavior (and might well be the source of your problems) because you're writing to the wrong memory location.

The correct way to do this is looping from `0` to `i < sizeof(pins) / sizeof(pins[0])` (notice the **strict** less-than `<` operator) which ranges from `0` to `length(pins) - 1` and then just `String pinNumber = String(i + 1);`. That way, `1H` will change the value of `pinValues[0]`, mapping you 1-indexed serial messages to 0-indexed C arrays.

## Looping is unnecessary

I'm not sure why you're looping over `pins`. You're doing unnecessary work and probably hogging the uC (specially since, as Dave Tweed points out in the other answer, you're using expensive functions such as `String` and string comparison with `==`).

`message` has a single instance, e.g., `1H\n` so there's no loop needed. `char pinNumber = message[0] - '0';` will store the integer value of the first character in `pinNumber`, with which you're then able to index the array.

How does that work?

- `message[0]` would be a `char` type (e.g. `'1'`)
- `'0'` is also a `char`, which corresponds to the ASCII value of 0 (48 in decimal).
- If `message[0]` contains the char `'0'`, then the result is `'0' - '0' == 48 - 48 == 0`
- Since numbers are contiguous and increasing in [the ASCII set](http://www.asciitable.com/) the result of the subtraction is the actual number as a single byte integer.
- `'1' - '0' == 49 - 48 == 1` and on and on.

You might also want to reject bogus input:

```
if (pinNumber >= sizeof(pins) / sizeof(pins[0]))
  return;
```

## More spurious work

At each `loop()` iteration you do this:

```
// Write to pins        
for (int i = 1; i <= sizeof(pins) / sizeof(pins[0]); i++) {
  digitalWrite(pins[i], pinValues[i]);
}
```

Which has the same problem with the out-of-bounds as before.

It also does unnecessary work, since you're writing **ALL** pin values, whether they changed or not! Why don't you `digitalWrite(pins[pinNumber], HIGH or LOW);` directly in `setPinValues` and avoid this loop? You could even get rid of the `pinValues` array if you don't really need to store them (or you can keep it if you need it for some reason).

## My alternative setPinValues

```
void setPinValue(char pin, char value) {
  char pinNumber = pin - '0';  // Get the integer value of the ASCII char

  if (pinNumber >= sizeof(pins) / sizeof(pins[0]))  // Reject out-of-bounds input
    return;

  switch (value) {
    case 'H':
      pinValues[pinNumber] = HIGH;  // Not necessary if you don't want to store the pin values
      digitalWrite(pins[pinNumber], HIGH);
      break;
    case 'L':
      pinValues[pinNumber] = LOW;  // Not necessary if you don't want to store the pin values
      digitalWrite(pins[pinNumber], LOW);
  }
}
```

And then just call it from `loop()` as `setPinValue(message[0], message[1]);`

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you! If there are more than 10 pins so theres the possibility of receiving `13H\n`, will `char pinNumber = message[0] - '0';` still work? I'm thinking of splitting a message like `13H\n` into `13` and `H` using `strstr()` but I'm not sure how it can be done

Comment: @Nyxynyx not without a loop scanning all characters. In that case [`String.toInt()`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToInt) is your best friend. IIRC, you don't even need to split the string since `.toInt()` will parse up to the first non-numeric character so, as long as your string starts with the pin number it will be alright. It'd be great if you confirm if `.toInt()` works like that, for future reference!

Comment: Yes `String.toInt()` does work as expected! To compare the last char H or L, I use the code I've just updated the original question with. Will that be optimal? Used `if` conditionals because when using `switch`, I received the error `switch quantity not an integer`

Comment: @Nyxynyx `switch quantity not an integer` means you didn't put `char` as the type of your switch value, am I right? `char` is an integer data type, so it must work (if not, just `(int)` cast it!) Also, `[]` works with `String` AFAIK, so you don't need the convoluted `.substring` and `.toCharArray` section, just `message[message.length() - 1]` to get the `'H'` or `'L'`.

Comment: @Nyxynyx (edit time passed) actually it'd be `message[message.length() - 2]` to take the `\n` into account, though I'd go simpler and just `message += received;` **only if** `received != '\n'`.

Comment: I used `message.replace("\n", "");` which I'm guessing is slower

Comment: @Nyxynyx `'\n'` is a single char (if it weren't, you couldn't put it between single quotes). You might be mistaking it for `"\r\n"` (notice the double quotes, it's a string of chars) which is a Windows-only convention, only for text files and completely unrelated to serial communications which are encoding agnostic. Don't use `.replace` or anything like that, it's slower and unnecessary. In embedded devices you should keep things to the bare minimum!

Comment: That's such a thorough answer it deserves a +2! Numerous coding sins covered and corrected in style.

Comment: If I was using more than 10 pins, I'd change the message format to always use two digits for the pin number: 01H, 05L, 13H, etc.  That way, the H/L is always string[2], for easy access.

Answer (score 4):

It's a performance issue. The first version of `setPinValues()` is making many calls to `String()` each time it is called, and this is a nontrivial function. This causes `setPinValues()` to take much longer than you think to finish, so it isn't too surprising that the Arduino eventually can't keep up with the incoming messages at 57600 bps.

In the second version of `setPinValues()`, the arguments to the `String()` calls are all constants, so they get evaluated at compile time. This version runs much faster, and it is able to keep up at 57600.